# I dont get all rows with the contain function

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a varchar(max) and I create a full text index. Then I use this query:

```
select * from Mytable where contains(Field, '68396.68403.');
```

But I have only get one result, the row that has the value "68396.68403". But I have more rows like "68396.68403.xxxx", "68396.68403.yyy", etc. that I don't get as result. But they contais "68396.68403.".

What is the problem?

i am using Sql Server 2014 express and as stopword I am using "system".

If I get the stopword that I have with this query:

```
SELECT stopword FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords
```

I don't have any row.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a prefix:

```
select *
from Mytable
where contains(Field, '68396.68403.*');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works. By I would like to ask, does not contains the meaning to get rows which contais the string? Why have I to use the "*" to get the exptected results? Thanks.

Comment: With this soulution I get the solutions 68396.68403.XXX.YYY but not the 68396.68403.XXX I means that I don't get the results that has only 2 or three numbers.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía I believe it is because the full text engine treats "68396.68403.XXX.YYY" as a single word (the periods are not word breakers in this case), so you have to use wildcards to force a substring match.